# Help with Independent Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, independence, dice

**There are n dice of different colors being rolled simultaneously. The numbers that show up on the faces are
added up to compute X. How many different die rolls result in X being divisible by 3? (basically how many
of the n tuples with each number being between 1 and 6 are such that the sum of these n numbers is divisible
by 3)**

I was having some problem figuring out how exactly to answer this question. We discussed how to solve this problem using a known number of dice, but I can't figure out how I would accomplish this using a variable number of dice, as it is hard to calculate the possibility of all numbers that the dice can sum to and be divisible by 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- How many $n$-tuples are possible in total?
- What proportion have a sum which is a multiple of $3$? (Easier than you might think at first - consider the effect of the last dice to roll)

Comment: I have determined that there are 2n numbers that n dice can sum to that are divisible by 3 (3 dice can sum to 3, 6 , 9, 12, 15, 18). However, I still do not know how to determine what proportion sum to a multiple of 3

Comment: @dumon__: That was not quite the question I was suggesting in my second point.  Better to think that after $n-1$ dice rolls you have a sum between $n-1$ and $6n-6$, and two of the next six numbers are a multiple of $3$.  So, no matter what that sum is, there is a chance of $\frac26$ that the final roll will end up with a sum which is  a multiple of $3$